# Getting $scope object in Angular's run() method

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to do some stuff when my app loads to set up the default state. So I'm trying to use the run method on the Module object. When I try to access the $scope variable though I get an "Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined" message in my console.

See the following example http://jsfiddle.net/F2Z2X/1/

```
app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope){
    $scope.data = { myvariable: 'Hello' };
});

app.run(
    alert($scope.data.myvariable))
);
```

Am I going about this all wrong?

For example, I want to run the watchAction function once at the beginning, to hide UI elements that aren't called for yet, but the watchAction function doesn't have the $scope object because it's not being called by the watch method so I have to pass it to it, but alas it's not available.

Comment: .run gets run once at the very beginning of initialization. I don't think it makes a lot of sense to have a $scope at that point. You can pass in $rootScope tho.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.someData = {message: "hello"};
});
```

You can only get `$rootScope` injected to `services` and `run` function, because each `child scope` is inherited from its parent scope and the top level scope is `rootScope`. Since it would be ambigous to inject *any* scope. Only root scope is provided.

Comment: 1 question: If I add any event handlers in the run block like `$rootScope.on('myevent',function(){})`.... how should I call $destroy? On $rootScope itself? Because if I don't do, I get lint error.... and can't use $scope in run block.

Answer (score 3):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    // use .run to access $rootScope
    $rootScope.rootProperty = 'root scope';
});

app.controller("ParentCtrl", ParentCtrlFunction);
app.controller("ChildCtrl", ChildCtrlFunction);
function ParentCtrlFunction($scope) {
    // use .controller to access properties inside ng-controller
    //in the DOM omit $scope, it is inferred based on the current controller
    $scope.parentProperty = 'parent scope';
}
function ChildCtrlFunction($scope) {
    $scope.childProperty = 'child scope';
    //just like in the DOM, we can access any of the properties in the
    //prototype chain directly from the current $scope
    $scope.fullSentenceFromChild = 'Same $scope: We can access: ' +
    $scope.rootProperty + ' and ' +
    $scope.parentProperty + ' and ' +
    $scope.childProperty;
}
```

for Eg. https://github.com/shekkar/ng-book/blob/master/7_beginning-directives/current-scope-introduction.html

It is simple flow ,we have rootScope,parentScope,childScope .in each section we are assigning the corresponding scope variables.we can access the $rootScope in parentScope, rootScope and parentScope in childScope.

Comment: what's the point in adding a new answer to a question that was answered and accepted almost a year ago?

Comment: I would like to share my knowledge ,in this eg it explains the rootScope to parentScope and parentScope to childScope and url explains compete html code , i hope this may helpful for @Tristan and others

Comment: Thanks Shekkar, Please explain the meaning of your code snippet. A code snippet by itself is not helpful.

Comment: I think this is the most correct answer since it describes how to solve the actual problem. Thank you @Shekkar!