# Adding a Self-Executing Anonymous Function to extend Sir Trevor in AngularJS whilst accessing $

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an App written using AngularJS (which I am very new to) and within my app I am using the Sir Trevor content editor. I need to extend the Sir Trevor content editor to include some custom blocks I have written. Everything is fine however I need to use an angular services within my extension code (the things pre-fixed with $, for example $translate).

Now within my app my Sir Trevor extension code is merely included in a file that has a Self-Executing Anonymous Function like so...

```
(function() {

    // check SirTrevor exists...
    if(SirTrevor){

        SirTrevor.Blocks.NewBlock = SirTrevor.Block.extend({

        // yadda yadda

        })

        SirTrevor.Blocks.AnotherNewBlock = SirTrevor.Block.extend({

        // blah blah blah

        })
     }

})()
```

Now when I try and pass my angular method in as an argument to the function it won't be recognized as it doesn't exist. Thus I need to put my Self-Executing Anonymous Function somewhere that can access the angular services. A `.directive` isn't suitable as I don't wish to add a tag or attribute to my HTML and I only wish to execute this code once. The code doesn't seem suitable for a `.factory` as I don't return an object and my code isn't a singleton so `.service` is out, and I am unsure where I would invoke/call this? Where or how should I execute my code so I can access/inject angular services?

Does anyone have any ideas?

BTW: I can't add the new code to my SirTrevor.js as it will be overwritten the next time I update the dependency or run `bower install`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'angular methods'? 'The things prefixed with $' sounds more like angular services

Comment: The only valid place for the plugin is inside the directive. It doesn't matter if you're going to use the plugin in only one place, and you don't really need to add extra tags or attributes to your HTML, because directives can be referenced by CSS class as well. And even if you do need to add an attribute I don't see why would that pose a problem?

Comment: You can use `.run()`, but I'm not sure what you mean by "it won't be recognized"

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. Andrey - I have updated the question. zeroflagL - by "it won't be recognized" I mean if I pass in the service like so (function($whatever){})($whatever)

Comment: Sure, but where does `$whatever` come from? You somehow need to get a reference to the service. Or is that the actual question, "how do I get a reference to a service"?

Comment: .run() helped... I also looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371687/getting-scope-object-in-angulars-run-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely correct. This is purely for configuration so it does not fit in any component below.

- Directive, which is for DOM manipulation
- Service, which returns a singleton object that will be called with the `new` operator.
- Factory, which returns a singleton object.

It might also work in a `.config()` block, but I would use a `.run()` block. See [Module documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module).

### Example

```
(function(angular, SirTrevor) {

    angular.module('myApp', [])
        .run(['$http', function($http) {

            // $http is injected by Angular.

            if (SirTrevor) {
                SirTrevor.Blocks.NewBlock = SirTrevor.Block.extend({
                    // Whatever here...
                });

                SirTrevor.Blocks.AnotherNewBlock = SirTrevor.Block.extend({
                    // Whatever here...
                });
            }
        }]);

})(angular, SirTrevor);
```

Comment: Excellent, however the item fails/ breaks my build as the service I pass is not found or it is not available yet: angular.module('myApp', []).run(['$translate', function($translate)

However this works locally?

Comment: There's no Angular service called `$translate` out of the box. Are you using [this module](http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate/)? In that case you need to replace the empty array (`.module('myApp', [])`) with the module which contains the `$translate` service, i.e. `.module('myapp', ['pascalprecht.translate'])`.

Comment: Strangly when I add the empty array or ['pascalprecht.translate'] it breaks the Sir Trevor content editor? How strange?

Comment: Would you mind posting or providing a link to your code? Or jump into [JabbR](https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/AngularJS) so we can discuss it on chat.