# Don't execute .run() until AngularJS service ($) is available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

Following on from my previous question: [Adding a Self-Executing Anonymous Function to extend Sir Trevor in AngularJS whilst accessing $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112358/adding-a-self-executing-anonymous-function-to-extend-sir-trevor-in-angularjs-whi/21113614?noredirect=1#21113614)

I run some configuration code to extend the Sir Trevor Content Editor, then to reduce or remove a dependency I inject the $translate service into the code.

```
   angular.module('myApp', [])
        .run(['$translate', function($translate) {

            // $translate is injected by Angular.

            if (SirTrevor) {
                SirTrevor.Blocks.NewBlock = SirTrevor.Block.extend({
                    // Whatever here... then
                    title: function() {
                        return $translate('some.path.somewhere');
                    }
                });

                SirTrevor.Blocks.AnotherNewBlock = SirTrevor.Block.extend({
                    // Whatever here... then
                    title: function() {
                        return $translate('some.other.path.somewhere');
                    }
                });
            }
        }]);
```

All works well on my local machine however when deploying to my build server the build breaks! The culprit is that `$translate` isn't ready or available when my code executes? I'm wondering if it is possible to addd some kind of `$watch` or function to execute the code when the `$translate` service is available?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say translate service is not available what do you mean. The service can provide its own state if required.

Answer (score 0):

DI will resolve all dependencies before injecting and executing the code.  For services, this means the singleton will be instantiated once (lazily) before injection.

If your service needs to do some async things before it is useful you may want to return a promise and use `.then()` to ensure everything is fully resolved.  I'm not sure which `$translate` you are using, but one like http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate/ will return a promise and also broadcast events when stuff is loaded.