# Unknown provider: $scopeProvider initialling angularjs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got this error Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope

with below app.js

```
(function() {
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', 'satellizer'])
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $authProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
      })
  })
  .run(function($rootScope, $scope, $window, $location) {
    if ($window.localStorage.user) {
      $rootScope.currentUser = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.user);
    }

    $scope.test = 'test';

  });
})();
```

Comment: Application run phase `$scope` isn't available, that's why you can't inject `$scope` dependency out there

Comment: you csn have `$rootscope` in `run` block

Comment: @PankajParkar run is like before rendering?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject `$scope` into your application run function.

> You can only get $rootScope injected to services and run function, because each child scope is inherited from its parent scope and the top level scope is rootScope. Since it would be ambigous to inject any scope. Only root scope is provided.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17371896/3453034

Here is some information on run blocks taken from [Angular's module documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/ce669edfa14dc7eb7c389d2f82c9c98399a9009b/docs/content/guide/module.ngdoc):

> Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. A run block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the application. It is executed after all of the service have been configured and the injector has been created. Run blocks typically contain code which is hard to unit-test, and for this reason should be declared in isolated modules, so that they can be ignored in the unit-tests.

You can set `$rootScope.test = "test"` in your run method, inject `$rootScope` into your controller, and access it in your controller directly via `$rootScope`.